# Using a value from a dropdown list in a handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I could really use some help if anyone can spare some time. I am trying to access the value of a dropdownlist (dropdownlist1) on the master page from my content page and then use the variable in a hanlder in a .ashx code page. To test it I was trying to display the varialble in a message box. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Content Page (dropdownlist is on master page)

```
$(document).ready(function $("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
            location.reload;


            alert($(this).val());
            strTrail = $(this).val();
            alert(strTrail);

        });
```

Handler

```
Case "SearchByLocation"
            Dim firstTime As Integer = 0
            Dim latitude As String = "42.9901009" 'context.Request("Latitude")
            Dim longitude As String = "-81.146698" 'context.Request("Longitude")
            'Dim fromdate As String = context.Request("#DropDownList1").val


            Dim strTrail As String = context.Request("#DropDownList1")
            MsgBox("now")
            MsgBox(strTrail)
            'strTrail = context.Request("strTrail")
            If firstTime < 1 Then
                strTrail = "Lookout"
            End If


            Dim objCBL As New JParkinsonLookUP.JPLookUp

            Dim objDS As System.Data.DataSet = objCBL.SearchByTrail(strTrail, latitude, longitude, 10)

            'result = "{""Locations"":[{""ID"":""1"",""Latitude"":""28.537"",""Longitude"":""-81.380""}]}"

            result = "{""Locations"":["
            For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In objDS.Tables(0).Rows

                result += "{""ID"":""" & dr("ID").ToString() & """,""Latitude"":""" & dr("Latitude").ToString() & """,""Longitude"":""" & dr("Longitude").ToString() & """},"
            Next

            result = result.Substring(0, result.LastIndexOf(","))

            result += "]}"
            firstTime = 1


        Case "SearchByDescription"


    End Select


    'second command
    'third command

    context.Response.Write(result)



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

firt of all avoid **msgbox** coz it will throw in exception (not valid in an aspnet page contest)

Second one when you will go through document.ready you will have to make a ajax request as per your code you will return json object then you need to parse within javascript the object ad read value from it.

```
   $.ajax(
{
type: "GET", url: url, data: qry,
success: function (msg) {
    lat = msg.Locations[0].Latitude;
    lng = msg.Locations[0].Longitude;
   alert(lat +' ' + lat);
},
error: function (msg) {
    $("#coor").html("errore durante l'elaborazione");
}
});
```

Another important stuff use this directive to set your response:

```
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Take care to check via Chrome or Firefox your response and call via network call so you will able to have more info.
this is code is not test i use some working code at my end and make some changes to let you an idea.